# Inequalities identification

Tags: inequality

Here's the question -

$$4 \le x \le 12$$

$$-6 \le y \le 2$$

Find the smallest possible value of $\frac{2x} {y}$

My answer is correct but I'm never sure why was it correct -

$$\frac{2x}{ y} = \frac{2(12)}{(-1)} = -24$$

Why must I use $-1$ as the value to get smallest possible value and not '$0$' ? Is it because that I can't divide a number by $0$ ?

So does this mean that in the future if I see let's say smallest possible value of $\frac{x}{y}$ and the  range of $y$ includes $0$, I don't use $0$ but use $-1$ ?

Comment: Opps ... Sorry it was a typo . Was looking at a different question when I typed it out . @GoodDeeds

Comment: There is no smallest value, $x=4,y=-0.1,-0.01,\cdots$: $8/(-0.1)=-80,$ $8/(-0.01)=-800, ...$

Comment: Can $x, y$ be only integers?  Any real numbers?  If only integers, then your answer is correct as division by zero is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I give here a way of representing the information $2x/y$, and then be convinced (even if you have, besides, to demonstrate it). In fact, the quantity $2x/y$ is *invariant* on a given line through the origin (we have represented a few of these values on a graphic, for example, point $(12,1)$ is associated with the value $2*12/1=24$). These values are in descending or ascending order as you turn in the anticlockwise or clockwise sense, with abrupt changes in $0$ and $\pi$ (180 degrees). It remains to pick up the coordinates of the point providing the minimal value $-24$, i.e., $(12,-1)$.

[image: The set of lines through the origin : a projective view...]

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily, forget about the negative sign for $y$. If a number is large and positive, then adding a negative sign will make it as small (i.e. negative) as it was 'large' before. So we want the largest positive value of $2x/y$ where both $x$ and $y$ are positive. The only condition on $y$ is that in the original range, the value we chose must be able to have a negative sign. We take the largest $x = 12$ and the smallest *positive* $y = 1$ (remember we are ignoring negative signs for $y$ but we want to make it negative later; also, no division by zero) and we get 24; with the minus sign, this becomes $-24$.